# Не выполняется запрос к MySQL

Tags: php

Решил освоить `php` и столкнулся с проблемой. В дебаге ошибок не показывает. Пытался написать скрипт новостей. Соединение с БД вроде как проходит, но текста нету. 
Файл `config`:

```
<?

$dbhost = "localhost";  
$dbuser = "root";   
$dbpass = ""; 
$dbname = "dble";

?>
```

Файл `index`:

```
session_start(); 
define( '_JEXEC', 1 ); 
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass); 
mysql_select_db( $dbname, $db );

require 'core/config.php';

include_once('core/sheild.php'); //* Это цепляется защита от sql иньекций*//

function query($sql) { 
    mysql_set_charset(‘utf8); 
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$query) { 
        trigger_error(mysql_error() . $sql); 
    }

    $result = array(); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { 
        $result[] = $row; 
    } 
    return $result; 
}
```

Файл `main` (шаблон с формами):

```
<?php 
//* Пропустил весь код html *// 
defined('_JEXEC') or die(' <style type="text/css"> 
body {background: url("error.png") repeat-y right #bcc5ca; font-family: arial; width: 99.8%; color:#9A022B; text-shadow:2px 2px 2px #ccc; overflow: hidden;} 
h1 { font-size: 48px; margin: 0 20px;} 
p {font-size: 32px; margin: 20px; } 
img {margin: 0;} 
a {text-decoration: none;} 
</style> <H2>Ошибка 403 <br> Доступ запрещён! '); ?>

...

<?php 
$result = query('select news.content from news'); 
echo $query; 
?>
```

БД:

```
CREATE TABLE `news` ( 
`content` varchar(600) NOT NULL, 
`Date` date NOT NULL, 
`Title` varchar(30) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `news` (`content`, `Date`, `Title`) VALUES 
('hello world', '2013-05-13', 'test');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_set_charset(‘utf8);
```

У вас тут случаем нет очепятки, ничего не забыли закрыть?

```
<?php
$result = query('select news.content from news'); 
echo $query; 
?>
```

Я так полагаю это вывод новостей? Если так, то делать это надо через цикл while:

```
$result = mysql_query('select news.content from news'); 
while($mynews = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $mynews['Date']."<br/>".$mynews['Title']."<br/>".$mynews['content'];
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Сейчас попробую. Надеюсь заработает. =)